# Use Image in the INPUT control

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a DotNet Core project where I am trying to use an image in the `INPUT` tag. If I use the `BUTTON` control I am unable to call the `asp-page-handler`.
Here is my sample.

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login to MyApp" asp-page-handler="RedirectToMyApp" />
```

Comment: where is image?

Comment: It is in the same project (src="~/images/MyApp-Logo.png")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the type to 'image' instead of 'submit'.

```
<input type="image" src="img_submit.gif" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48">
```

Please refer here for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_image.asp

Comment: Thank you, I used it as below and it is working for me.
`<form asp-page-handler="RedirectToMyApp">
    <input type="image" src="~/images/MyApp-Logo.png" alt="Submit">
</form>`